# Historical figure word-search

Tags: anagram, history, word-search

[image: wordsearch]

There are 22 historical figures on this board. Can you find them all?

Comment: very nice! i got 10 ... is diagonal valid?

Comment: Yes, diagonal is valid, too.

Comment: The only valid paths are lines, columns and diagonals. Is this correct?

Comment: If we talk about paths, this is correct. There is more to this puzzle, though. @Ivanhoe

Comment: The fact that you said something was missing from one of the names coupled with your confession about not knowing who Volta was leads me to think you expected Voltaire. Would I be correct in assuming this?

Comment: Your assumption is not entirely true. And something is still missing from one of the names. @Ivanhoe

Comment: @MariaDeleva Does the 'anagram' tag mean that some of the names are actually scrambled?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov, it means something else. I will leave it at that.

Comment: Does Lear count? As in King Lear known from Shakespeares tragedy that holds the same name, based on somewhat reality?

Comment: @MasterOfMuppets, no.

Comment: It's times like this that I wish questions were +10...

Comment: @Mithrandir, I actually did a lousy job with this question, although I worked several hours on it. I did a few mistakes that I should have noticed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle)   (10,11 - 10,3)
>  [Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Sebastian_Bach) (7,9 - 4,6)
>  [Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar)   (4,1 - 9,1)
>  [Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) (4,1 - 4,9)
>  [Cleopatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra)  (12,10. 12,2)
>  [Curie](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Curie)  (3,7 - 3,3)
>  [Da Vinci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci)  (5,3 - 11,3)
>  [Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison) (10,1 - 5,6)
>  [Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) (8,9 - 2,9)
>  [Gogh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh)  (7,2 - 3,2)
>  [Joan Of Arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_of_Arc) (13,2 - 13,10)
>  [Lama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalai_Lama) (4,8 - 1,8)  - As in Dalai Lama.
>  [Lenin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Lenin) (7,5 - 11,1)
>  [Monroe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Monroe) (2,8 - 2,3) I refuse to link Marilyn. She's not "historical" :)
>  [Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato)  (9,7 - 13,3)
>  [Poe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Allan_Poe) (12,6 - 12,8) - thanks @Kruga - this was not intended
>  [Ramses II](http://www.ancient-egypt-online.com/ramses-II.html)  (1,9 - 1,4)
>  [Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt)  (4,4 - 12,4)
>  [Stalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin) (11,7 - 11,2)
>  [Twain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Twain) (1,10 - 5,6)
>  [Wilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Wilde)  (2,9 - 6,9)

The rest are here just because I was instructed to add them so the puzzle would be complete.
All credits go to [Kruga](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41443/19989). I would not be able to find them otherwise.

From the remaining letters you can form:

> [Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart)
>  [Voltaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire)
>  [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes)

Comment: @Marius, if you noticed the comment I made to Radoslav, this is not what I meant with anagrams. Did you notice that I am very eager to remove some non-intended answers, while I let other be? Like Poe, or Nunh (suggested by Yandrakus). Have a break. The puzzle will be right here. Unless someone solves it. I promise I won't give away anything more for at least a couple of hours. :)

Comment: @Marius I think you should use Kruga's answer to complete the puzzle, yes your answer is most complete.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the hints given, I believe we have to use the unused letters as an anagram, which can make

> [Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart)
>  [Voltaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire)
>  [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes)
>
>  Leaving us with D and U unused

Comment: You are correct! @Kruga.

Comment: @MariaDeleva but there is no I letter left to be used. Unless the pharaoh in question is I and not II

Comment: The I in the bottom left corner is unused

Comment: @Kruga - you are right, missed this one

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

A [little helper](https://wordsearch.lukasjoswiak.com/p/1582123) for those still searching the missing 3 words

> Bach - thanks @Marius
> Caesar
> da Vinci
> Roosevelt
> Wilde
> Churchill
> Joan of Arc
> Aristotle
> Ramses
> Monroe
> Curie
> Einstein
> Stalin
> Plato
> Lenin
> Edison
> Cleopatra
> Twain
> Bach
> Gogh

Comment: One of them is missing something. :)

Comment: And Celler was also not intended. Ah. Perhaps I should change a bit the puzzle to avoid these not intended finds?

Comment: PS. I made an edit - changed the places of two letters only, to avoid Volta and Celler in the answers. Sorry for that.

Comment: @MariaDeleva NP, I removed them from my list.

Comment: Only the bottom part of the little helper could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I got a few only: (you can use them in your answers)

> Einstein (8,8 - 8,2)
>  Stalin (11,7 - 11,2)
>  Cleopatra (12,10 - 12,1)
>  Joan of Arc (13,2, 13,10)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Horizontal:

> Caesar,
>  Gogh,
>  Da Vinci,
>  Roosevelt,
>  Wilde,
>  Aristotle,
>  Nuhn, ([Ferner Nuhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferner_Nuhn) dunno if correct but I'm quite sure that it isn't xD)

Vertical:

> Ramses,
>  Monroe,
>  Curie,
>  Churchill,
>  Einstein,
>  Stalin,
>  Cleopatra,
>  Joan of Arc,

Diagonal:

> S. Bach (Sebastian Bach as @MasterofMuppets suggest?),
>  Twain,
>  Edison,
>  Lenin,
>  Plato,

Comment: Marius already has most of the answer figured out. Only the last 3 remain. But there the logic is different (there is one more tag to this puzzle - anagram). P.S. Nuhn, as well as Poe, were not intended, but could be bonus ones.

Comment: Yep, I saw the anagram tag but since you said "it means something else" I'm still guessing what are you refering to. Because I found Carnot but in a quite messy way that doesn't fit on the 3 categories I posted on my partial answer.

Comment: The final 3 wouldn't fit these 3 categories. But Carnot is not amongst them.

Comment: Could be that the remaining 3 names should be build around the spare letters?

Comment: @Yandarkus, maybe... Did you try something?

Comment: Well with the spare letters I managed to build Lavoisier... but I don't get anything else with the rest, at least for the moment!

Comment: Nevermind, I need to check it again after I read the comment about Ramses!